# Unable to set member variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Very strange issue.

I have the following code:

```
NSDictionary* notificationUserInfo = [pNotification userInfo];
NSManagedObject* newShoppingFilter = [notificationUserInfo valueForKey:@"shoppingListFilter"];
self.shoppingListFilter = newShoppingFilter;
NSLog(@"%@ tapped", [newShoppingFilter valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

For some reason the self.shoppingListFilter = newShoppingFilter is not setting the variable.

I assume that this is some issue with not initializing the self.shoppingListFilter variable in some way but I cannot figure this out.  The NSLog shows the right output, newShoppingFilter is not null but self.shoppingListFilter is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is `shoppingListFilter` being declared in your code originally? Moreover, is `[notificationUserInfo valueFoeKey:@"shoppingListFilter"]` not null?

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid and don't know how objective-c works but I declare shoppingListFilter in my.h as property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject* shoppingListFilter; and synthesize it in my .m file.  I do not initialize it anywhere which may be the problem.  @esqew

Comment: Did you synthesize your property?

Comment: Are you using `@dynamic` or `@synthesize` in your .m for shoppingListFilter?  Are you over riding the setter (`- (void)setShoppingListFilter:(NSManagedObject *)newShoppingListFilter {` or something similar in your .m file)?

Answer (score 1):

I bet newShoppingFilter is nil. Most likely, there is no key "shoppingListFilter" in the notification user info dictionary.

Set a breakpoint at the line that assigns a value to self.shoppingListFilter and check the value of newShoppingFilter. Also display the entire contents of notificationUserInfo.

Post the code that creates the user info dictionary and passes it into the notification that you are posting. That would help track down the problem.

Comment: The body of the question says that the `NSLog()` reveals that `newShoppingFilter` is a valid object.